# xcode 4.2 + xcode project from makefile

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, makefile

I am trying to build c++ xcode application from makefile.
I am using xcode 4.2, and in this version i dont see command line utility->standard tool.. All the help says "If you are just trying to build a command-line utility, selectone of the tools—for example, Standard Tool."

I have installed command line tools from preferences->downloads->components
Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have "Command Line Tool" available when starting a new project in "OS X"->"Application". If you don't, try updating your softwares, including XCode.

Comment: I found command line tool under application. Now how would i add existing make file and the source files for xcode project?

Comment: Once the project is created, click on "File"->"New"->"Target" and under "OS X" -> "Other" you will find External Build System. Name the target however you like ("Build with Make" for instance), and the Build settings for this new target should appear. Switch to the "Info" tab and pick as the Directory the directory where your makefile is. Don't forget to use that target you just created for your project.

Comment: thanks a lot. i am not able to use the new created target for the project. please how would i do this?